# How to change the data in script tags in html from js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mean-stack, mean

I have the following script tag in my html,

```
 <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
          "@context": "http://schema.org",
          "@type": "VideoObject",
          "name": "Title",
          "description": "Video description",
          "thumbnailUrl": [
            "https://www.xpertdox.com/assets/images/XperDox_Cover_Art .png"
           ],
          "uploadDate": "2015-02-05T08:00:00+08:00",
          "duration": "PT1M51S",
          "embedUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDIYgpraBHA",
          "interactionCount": "2347"
        }
    </script>
```

I want to append values to this through my js file,like

```
"name": "My Title",
"description": "My description"
```

But i dont know how to assign values to the script tag form js.I am using angular js.Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks..

Comment: Is your JSON object not mapped to a variable of some kind? By itself, it wouldn't output anything to the page.

Comment: As @ObsidianAge said, that object isn't accessible without being assigned to a variable. like `let yourObj = {all that content}` then you can have `yourObj.name = "My Title"` or `yourObj["name"] = "My Title"`

Answer (score 0):

I am somewhat confused by exactly what you mean but have created a snippet of something that might be helpful.

It is possible to get the content from your json-script-tag element using JavaScript by getting a reference to it using a id or query selector.

Once you have a reference, you can parse the text of the json-script-tag into a JavaScript object and manipulate it as you would a normal object.

Finally, you can write the modified JSON back out to the script element although I am unsure under what circumstances this would be a suitable pattern for handling the passing of data.

```js
// get a reference to the script element
var jsonScript = document.querySelector('script[type="application/ld+json"]');
// parse the json-data element into a JS object
var json = JSON.parse(jsonScript.innerHTML)

// Set the object properties as required
json["name"] = "My Title"
json["description"] = "My description"

// write out the object back to the script tag (with pretty formatting)
// check in your browser developer tools to see the modified tag
jsonScript.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json, null, 2)

console.log('Script modified - check your developer tools to see the changes')
```

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
        {
          "@context": "http://schema.org",
          "@type": "VideoObject",
          "name": "Title",
          "description": "Video description",
          "thumbnailUrl": [
            "https://www.xpertdox.com/assets/images/XperDox_Cover_Art .png"
           ],
          "uploadDate": "2015-02-05T08:00:00+08:00",
          "duration": "PT1M51S",
          "embedUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDIYgpraBHA",
          "interactionCount": "2347"
        }
</script>
```